# What's the replacement in Dart 2.12 for the previous possibility to use switch with runtimeType?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used to be able before Flutter 2.0 / Dart 2.12 to do:

```
return BlocBuilder<MediaBloc, MediaState>(builder: (context, videoState) {
  switch (videoState.runtimeType) {
    case ReadyVideoState:
      return buildVideoWidget(context, videoState);
    default:
      throw ArgumentError.value(videoState);
  }
});
```

To call a function with the signature:

```
Widget buildVideoWidget(
    BuildContext context, ReadyVideoState readyVideoState) {
```

Now, I get the error:

```
The argument type 'MediaState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ReadyVideoState'.
```

`ReadyVideoState` is a subclass of `MediaState`. The compiler now complains about this call and says it doesn't work because videoState is of the type MediaState and not ReadyVideoState. Is there a new idiome to express what I want to express?

Comment: You should never use `runtimeType` for other than debugging. Always use e.g. `if (videoState is ReadyVideoState)`. Yes, it does means you cannot use a `switch` for type identification. The reason for `runtimeType` is bad is because it will always just return the the specific type of the object and does not tell us anything about if this object is compatible with a given interface.

Comment: @julemand101 : How about you turn the comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I will do that then. I was not sure if this was the answer you was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `runtimeType` for other than debugging. The problem is that it will always just return the the specific type of the object and does not tell us anything about if this object is compatible with a given interface. So if you have a object which extends from `ReadyVideoState` it will not be a `ReadyVideoState` if looking at `runtimeType` of this object. This the rarely what you want.

Instead, you should always use e.g. `if (videoState is ReadyVideoState)`. This will actually check of `videoState` is compatible with the type `ReadyVideoState` and will therefore work for objects which implement/extends `ReadyVideoState`.

Yes, it does unfortunately mean you cannot use a switch for type identification and you will therefore in some cases need a lot of `else if (...)`.

Comment: And don't forget, .runtimeType is *mangled* for the name shortening/obfuscation in release mode, so your carefully tested apps will break when published.